# Packstack Issues with External Networking and Floating IP Addresses

Tags: networking, centos, openstack

I've been working on getting a packstack configuration set up for a little while now, but have been left scratching my head here and could use any and all pointers for this one.

***The issue:***
Outbound access works for Nova guests, but inbound access doesn't seem to be working.

When I look at the output from  `ovs-vsctl show` I cannot see any of the ports for the floating IP addresses that I create within OpenStack. I see the port for the router interface that I created for external access (which I assume is why the outbound access is working), but no subsequent ports are added to br-ex.

If I check my DHCP client list on my dhcp server, I can see the IP address that got added to br-ex as an "anonymous device" - but the address is shown as taken as it should. In other words, my router acknowledges the existence of the first port that was added to the virtual bridge.

Any of the guests' floating IPs on the other hand, don't show in the main router. They seem to operate as if the public subnet that I created is just another internal network. For some reason, I am able to ping local addresses on my 'external' network (192.168.50.0/24) from a guest with or without a floating IP, but it doesn't seem like the openstack router can actually speak with the external network outside of that.

`ifconfig` now shows several `tap` interfaces, but I can't seem to coordinate these with any of the ports that Neutron/Openstack are creating - The mac addresses, IPs, and names don't match up, so I feel like that might just be a separate component that's making the new interfaces.

***The question(s):***

- Is there something that I'm missing that I need to do to get Neutron to attach ports marked as external to this particular bridge? Am I misunderstanding what needs to happen to get access to an internal OpenStack Guest machine from my external network?
- Are there log files for the creation of new Floating IP addresses? Could I reference something to find out where this mapping issue is occurring?
- What steps need to be taken beyond those described below in order to get floating IPs to work?

***The Configs:***

- manually configured the hardware interface to drop it's IP and join the OVS Bridge `BR-EX`  as an OVS Port, toggling the the `NMManaged`  key to `N`
- The packstack installer was run with the following command: `sudo packstack --default-password='Password' --allinone --provision-demo=n --os-neutron-l3-ext-bridge=br-ex --os-neutron-ovs-bridge-mappings=physnet:br-ex --os-neutron-ovs-bridge-interfaces=br-ex:enp0s20u3`
  Using this allowed me to map the port manually and successfully get outbound access to the external network.

I'm not sure what relevant information could help on this one, but let me know and I can get it to you. If I can expand on the above, just say where, and I'll drop some more info!